# Migrating an old old old VB + MSAccess program to a different computer

Tags: vb6, migration, odbc

I have an old program that was made for us a looong time ago. It consists of a large MDB (Access) file with all the data (no encryption, I can manually open the file and browse all the data) and an EXE file (probably VB?) that was custom made to easily manage the data in the file.

I'm trying to move this program for another user, to run in his own laptop.

First I tried just copying all the files, but I had MSCOM, GRD, LST, and ocx missing file errors. I tracked them all down and regsvr32'd them, and the program seemed to go a little further.

Then I got an ODBC connector error. Playing with ODBC sources manager and I added an entry with the name of the program that points to the specific MBD file. This helped too.

Now program starts and shows all menus, buttons and everything. However, the default record that should be onscreen is empty and as soon as I hit any control (next record, list, etc...) it crashes with a VB error 91:

[image]

> Run-time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

So it looks like the program can open the database file itself but it cant really access the data inside.

What else can I try to see what I need to set it all up correctly? Is there anything that "spies" inside and VB program to see how it's trying to access the MDB file?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Let me add this to my own questsion, second step after gain access to this program from another computer (locally in it) would be to try to move it to a server based database. Using the ODBC connector configuration, can I just switch the connector that's now using a local MDB file to use a network SQL server "transparently"? Because if so, this would probably save some effort in the first stage

Comment: ocx files would mostly likely mean vb6 rather than vb.net. You might try setting the compatibility mode for the exe file, and make sure the ODBC connection is using the right driver. Also, the way to add to your question is via the "edit" link.

Comment: Also, you will not be able to transparently change to using a networked SQL Server just by changing the ODBC connection. The reason is there are some SQL language differences between SQL Server and MS Access, where the program is almost certainly hard-coded to use MS Access-style syntax. However, you should be able to at least move the MDB file to a network share.

Comment: Finally, the exact text of the error would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Joel for your quick reply. Yes, it's definitely VB6, I used the "strings" command to extract all "valuable" text from the .exe and its clear now. I tried compatibility witn older OS's with no luck. Here's a link to a screenshot of the error: https://pasteboard.co/vvCyA99lSthR.png Thanks again

Comment: What a nightmare! I wouldn't like to be in your position. Visual Basic 6 has been out of long term support for a very long time now, and I would not try to install any VB6 apps on any other machine. I would seriously consider virtualising the machine which was running the application, and run it as a stand-alone VM on the new machine. Then bite the bullet and rewrite the application in a more modern development environment.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw AFAIK the VB6 runtime is still supported in Windows, though the VB6 IDE is not. Virtualization is one approach, the other would be to create an installer and a side-by-side manifest file for the EXE; both would improve stability enormously.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Whilst I appreciate Microsoft for making such efforts to keep backwards compatibility, it seems like a big risk to assume that binaries would keep running on modern machines for such a long time. I am not sure that manifests would help the situation.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw all I can say is that my own experience has been positive. Here's their official statement on this: "The Visual Basic team is committed to "It Just Works" compatibility for Visual Basic 6.0 applications on the following supported Windows operating systems:

Windows 11
Windows 10..." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause of your problem is some missing dll/ocx file referenced in your application. Open your exe file with notepad (or notepad++) and find all occurrences of .dll and .ocx files and check if those
files exist at user's laptop. If not, just copy them from your working machine and regsvr32 them.

Comment: Thanks Smith, Im trying to find a valid installer for Seagate Crystal Reports that works, as this seems to be what's missing (for now)

Answer (score 0):

I will go with @smith suggestion.

While looking at the error message on microsoft's website, below is the solution that applies to your scenerio

"The object is a valid object, but it wasn't set because the object library in which it is described hasn't been selected in the Add References dialog box."

So ensure all files are correctly copied to new system.

Comment: Ok I checked "strings" again inside the file. All OCX references in the program had already been installed (as the program failed due to these OCX missing files at startup), but I see over 100 references to p2sodbc.dll file in the .exe and text just above mentioning "Seagate Crystal Reports". So I understand that Im missing the whole Seagate CR suite, which I tried downloading from different web sources with no luck so far, only a true valid installer found that fails midway while installing...

Comment: Also when the program starts, before I touch any button and it fails, I see a .LDB file created which I believe means the MDB file has been succesfully opened, so this makes me believe the ODBC connector is actually working and all Im missing are DLL files like @smith and you say

Comment: Whats the new error message you are getting, or is it still runtime error 91?

Comment: Still the same as I have made no progress since I got that screenshot. I believe I need to install Crystal Reports but I don't know if "Seagate Crystal Reports" or "SAP Crystal Reports" or any other option I found online are all the same and valid or not... The only version I found for this installer failed during install

Comment: If there is a file p2sodbc.dll at your working machine (older CR versions 8 and 8.5 stored it in Windows\Crystal folder), check the file version regarding which  version of CR your old program requires.

Comment: I don't have the "source" computer with me, and I can't go there anytime but I will eventually be there again. I have found this path in the strings: C:\Archivos de programa\Seagate Software\Report Designer Component\craxdrt.dll